# POSTGRESQL Error: date format not recognized

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT
  v.accounting_date,
  v.payment_date
 FROM 
  (SELECT doc.document_id, 
  max(CASE WHEN doc.name='accountingDate' THEN doc.value END) AS accounting_date,
  max(CASE WHEN doc.name='paymentDate' THEN doc.value END) AS payment_date
  FROM go_appr_doc_variables doc
  GROUP BY doc.document_id) v
 WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(v.payment_date, 'YYYYMMDD')+8,'yyyymmdd') >= TO_CHAR(NOW(),'yyyymmdd')
```

v.accounting_date and payment_date values format is 'yyyymmdd'

I want to do payment_date for +8 days and compare it with the current date.

But there was a problem.

Comment: please provide example data, and explain what is the problem. from looking at your query, in general you should not convert to_char, and there are specific functions for dates if you want to add +8 days, for example, you can use: v.payment_date + interval '8 day'

Comment: 'yyyymmdd' is not a valid format. Moreover, you can compare dates directly without converting them back to char.

Comment: What is the data type of `doc.value`, `date` or `text`?

Comment: @Serg, sure it is: `select '20230607'::date; 2023-06-07` and `select to_date('20230607', 'yyyymmdd');  2023-06-07`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to manipulate and to compare dates,

Here's one option:

```
SELECT
  v.accounting_date,
  v.payment_date
 FROM 
  (SELECT doc.document_id, 
  MAX(TO_DATE(CASE WHEN doc.name='accountingDate' THEN doc.value END, 'yyyymmdd')) AS accounting_date,
  MAX(TO_DATE(CASE WHEN doc.name='paymentDate' THEN doc.value END, 'yyyymmdd')) AS payment_date
  FROM go_appr_doc_variables doc
  GROUP BY doc.document_id) v
 WHERE v.payment_date + INTERVAL '8 DAY' >= NOW()::DATE
```

explanation for this example:

- added "TO_DATE()" to the source query, to convert string to
  date field
- added "+ INTERVAL '8 DAY'" - which adds 8 days to a date field
- added "::DATE" - to truncate the time, keeping only the date part

Answer (score 0):

I assume `doc.value` is a properly formatted  string. You can compare dates directly after casting `NOW()` to `date` eliminating hours etc.

```
SELECT
  v.accounting_date,
  v.payment_date
 FROM 
  (SELECT doc.document_id, 
  max(CASE WHEN doc.name='accountingDate' THEN doc.value END) AS accounting_date,
  max(CASE WHEN doc.name='paymentDate' THEN doc.value END) AS payment_date
  FROM go_appr_doc_variables doc
  GROUP BY doc.document_id) v
 WHERE TO_DATE(v.payment_date, 'YYYYMMDD')+8 >= NOW()::date
```